# Missing keys of sorted array - rsort - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am doing an `rsort` for the following array.

```
$list_array = array("a1"=>$a1,"a2"=>$a2,"a3"=>$a3,"a4"=>$a4,"a5"=>$a5,"a6"=>$a6,"a7"=>$a7,"a8"=>$a8,"a9"=>$a9,"a10"=>$a10,"a11"=>$a11,"a12"=>$a12,"a13"=>$a13,"a14"=>$a14,"a15"=>$a15,"a16"=>$a16, "a17"=>$a17,"a18"=>$a18,"a19"=>$a19,"a20"=>$a20,"a21"=>$a21);

rsort( $list_array, SORT_NUMERIC );

print_r( $list_array );
```

Result

```
Array ( [0] => 32.87 [1] => 8.48 [2] => 8.34 [3] => 8.33 [4] => 7.85 [5] => 5.77 [6] => 3.75 [7] => 2.42 [8] => 1.24 [9] => 0.47 [10] => 0.09 [11] => 0.06 [12] => 0.01 [13] => 0.01 [14] => 0.01 [15] => 0.01 [16] => 0.01 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 )
```

The keys are missing.

How do I fix this to keep the keys in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`arsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) instead of `rsort`.

> Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association

Comment: If I use arsort, how do I print the first 3 items without knowing the title order?

Comment: You could do a few things, depending on the needs of your code--slicing, foreach with a counter, etc. But that's an entirely different question than the one you asked.